# How can I change the type of variable in the whole package with NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, variable-assignment

I am programming in Java. I have a variable defines as `long` and it is working alright. I want to change it now so the variable everywhere thought the project is defined as `BigInteger`. Is there a way I can easily do this with NetBeans?

Comment: The type of a variable is only declared once.

Comment: I know its already declared, I just want to change it, I don't want to manually go and type it in each file, I was hoping NetBeans can help me

Comment: I think you have to do it manually (using Ctrl + v). You can use Edit -> Replace in Projects. Check "whole words", "match
case"  and set file pattern to *.java to find the places it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it manually (using Ctrl + v). You can use Edit -> Replace in Projects. Check "whole words", "match case" and set file pattern to *.java to find the places it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Find if you IDE has replacement option, in Netbeans it is Control + H, search for the type AND name of the variable (for example "int myNumber" including the space to be replaced by "long myNumber" (I am assuming you used the same spacing all along), click replace all, you would have to do this in each class and then maybe change the datatype for the methods with return, but might be faster than old copy-paste.

Other solution:
I found a fix in oracle that might fit in here too, credit to @Zds:
Declare the variable upstream of where you declared the original one with the desired type you want, then review the class and accept the suggestions from the IDE to update the datatype.

The thread with the best solution is here:
[How to refactor variable type in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185480/how-to-refactor-variable-type-in-eclipse)