# Refactoring int,long etc

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, refactoring

Is there any possible way how to refactor variable fields in eclipse?

```
long interval;

public WebsiteConnectionPing(String url, long interval, String serviceName) {
    this.url = url;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}
//......
```

I want to refactor interval which is type long to type String is it possible?

```
String interval;

public WebsiteConnectionPing(String url, String interval, String serviceName) {
    this.url = url;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}
//....
```

Comment: but i did it manually

Comment: @Seda You can re-factor only variable names, but you cannot do that for Data Types. Seems NO.

Comment: @Eclipse You can't refactor method parameters in Eclipse?

Comment: so what is the best practice to change data type in some field? which is used many times in code

Comment: If you had confusion on data type of interval you could have gone for generic <T>.

Comment: What @KNU said. I think your only choice is to change them manually one by one, but you have [eclipse helping to change parameters and return types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5192608/3735079) going for you, which is nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refactor variable type in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185480/how-to-refactor-variable-type-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

I found this way:

1. Change type of argument "interval" in constructor from long to `String`.
2. Eclipse show error at line with code: `this.interval = interval;`
3. Choose the first quick-fix > Change type of 'interval' to `String`.