# Is there any type migration in eclipse just like in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, type-conversion, shortcut

Let's say I declare a variable in a java class and generate corresponding getters and setters.

```
public class Demo {

private String Id;

public String getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    Id = id;
}
```

}

For some reason I want to change the datatype of the variable "id" from String to int then I have to change the datatype of the variable manually everywhere in the program.
Is there any way I can refractor i.e type migrate the datatype of the variable.

The option is present in intellij idea but are there are any similar option in eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refactor variable type in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185480/how-to-refactor-variable-type-in-eclipse)

Comment: @VirtualJimi I suppose it is but the answers are not concrete. There are couple of hacks and no confirmation whether eclipse has that option or not.

Comment: @Artist I agree with you my friend it's drives me mad they put duplicates without even checking  if the answers are correct .